# Is waiting for an event that will never trigger a deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, terminology

A deadlock normally means that thread (or process) A is waiting for thread B, and at the same time thread B is waiting for thread A.

Currently I encountered a similar situation in our application. Thread A is waiting for an event to be set by thread B. However, thread B is **not** waiting for thread A, it just won't set the event (no matter for what reason). I am wondering whether this situation can also be called a "deadlock", or is there an other term for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd call it a bug or bad design. But it is not  deadlock if one thread is still running.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, no that's not deadlock, which is what you initially said (except that in general there could be a whole cycle of threads each waiting for the next one's lock: A->B->...->Z->A).

I think you could call it [resource starvation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_starvation), but that's quite a general term that also covers deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it a [starvation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_starvation) (ressource being CPU), not a [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I would call this a deadlock, too.

However, only one thread (Thread A) is affected from it, not the entire application.

Comment: I'd say that A is halted, not deadlocked. But it's really semantic quibling.

Comment: What Neil said. I'd say a deadlock is when two (or more) processes are waiting for **each other** to complete before they can proceed. Blocking (i.e. `Thread.Sleep(-1)`) indefinitely is not a deadlock.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I misunderstood the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my point of view :

A deadlock is a situation where the global state of the program does not progress anymore. 
If A is blocked but the program can still terminate because B may find a solution, it is not a deadlock.

Comment: *A deadlock is a situation where the global state of the program does not progress anymore.* :this definition would also fit the "livelock" case.

Comment: Well hum ... yes. I was just trying to answer the question, the part you mentioned is a required condition to be a deadlock. And it is *not* fulfilled in the bytepusher's question. It doesn't mean everything that fullfilled this condition is a deadlock. Just like a car usually has 4 wheels, but all vehicles with 4 wheels are not necessarily cars ...
(Ok I understand your point, I had to answer something)